# Error when trying to run pip

Tags: python, centos, pip, anaconda

My system is centos (linux). I have two Python versions, one is 2.7, the other is 3.6. I executed:

```
$ wget"https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.5.4.tar.gz#md5=834b2904f92d46aaa333267fb1c922bb"# tar -xzvf pip-1.5.4.tar.gz
$ cd pip-1.5.4
$ python setup.py install
```

But, when I tried to use `pip`, I got an error:

```
  File "/root/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2598, in load_entry_point
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2258, in load
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2264, in resolve
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py3.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py3.6.egg/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py3.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 1423, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

What can I do?

Comment: I guess that you can install it with yum.

Run as root:
   yum install python2-pip
or
   yum install python3-pip
depending on python version that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtualenv for specifying the version of python.

Virtualenvs help in solving library conflicts and it is good practice to use a different virtualEnv for every project.

Install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Add to .zshrc or .bashrc:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/code
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Specify which Python to use with mkvirtualenv:
virtualenvwrapper lets you specify the python executable without the path:

```
mkvirtualenv -python=python3 myVirtualEnv
```

Run: workon
A list of environments, empty, is printed.
Run mkvirtualenv to create a new virtualenv: mkvirtualenv temp
A new environment, temp is created and activated.
Run: `workon`
This time, the temp environment is included.
`workon temp` to work on the new virtualenv
use pip to install packages inside the virtualenv
After you're done using the virtualenv, simply deactivate out of it

(if you want to delete the virtualenv, use `rmvirtualenv`)
Use lssitepackages to list site-packages within the virtualenv.